# std::is_base_of for a ctor compiling error

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, sfinae

**Edited**

I have the following:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <type_traits>

class IListableItem {};
class SubIListableItem : public IListableItem {};
class Base{};
template<class T> struct is_listable_item : public std::false_type {};
template<class T> struct is_listable_item<std::is_base_of<IListableItem, T>> : public std::true_type {};
template<class T, std::enable_if_t<is_listable_item<T>::value, bool> = true>
class ImplementationOfBase : public Base
{
public:
    explicit ImplementationOfBase(const std::vector<T> &items): Base(){}
    virtual ~ImplementationOfBase(){}

protected:
    std::vector<std::wstring> getLabels(const std::vector<T> &source)
    {
    std::vector<std::wstring> ret;
    for (auto &i : source) ret.emplace_back(i.label);
    return ret;
    }
};

class Page : public ImplementationOfBase<SubIListableItem> {};

int main ()
{

}
```

It returns me:

```
prog.cc:34:58: error: no type named 'type' in 'struct std::enable_if<false, bool>'
   34 | class Page : public ImplementationOfBase<SubIListableItem> {};
      |                                                          ^
```

**I can't use pointers in this case**
Any clues?

Live example:
https://wandbox.org/permlink/ESviQ0qHrjLPX9wE

Thnks.

Comment: What errors do you get when you compile?

Comment: error C2993: 'std::enable_if<std::is_base_of<ListableItem,T>::value,bool>': illegal type for non-type template parameter '__formal'

Comment: Which compiler are you using? This is compiling fine for me with clang and intel compiler in Windows.

Comment: It [compiles for me](https://wandbox.org/permlink/1ipPwVIcXcwygpJl) too.

Comment: That's not how one uses SFINAE for class declaration... checkout online guides.

Comment: My previous comment was based on the original code and not the edited one.

Answer (score 0):

You can change the definition of `is_listable_item` as follows:

```
template<class T> struct is_listable_item : public std::is_base_of<IListableItem, T> {};
```

Your code is not working because `is_listable_item` has been specialized for `std::is_base_of<IListableItem, T>` but you are passing `SubIListableItem`.